# Issue with binding in DataGrid GoupStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, grouping

I am displaying jobs. Jobs got states like this:

```
public enum JobState
{
    Done,
    Running,
    Overdue,
    Disabled
}
```

When displaying the jobs in my `DataGrid` I group them by `State`, which is working as expected.

I followed this [example.](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) The problem is that I would like to add a header with the `Name` of the `State` to each grouping section.

Im just not sure what exactly is the `DataContext`of the `GroupItem`.

Maybe a `RelativeSource` helps ? - I was not able to make it ... any recommendations ?

---

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=JobCollectionView}" [..]>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
           <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=State}" />
               </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>                   
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                   <Setter Property="Template">
                      <Setter.Value>
                         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                             <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                  <Expander.Header>
                                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    //Error is here:     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StateDescription}" />
                                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                         <TextBlock Text=" Jobs"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                       </Expander.Header>
                                     <ItemsPresenter />
                                  </Expander>
                               </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                     </Style>
             </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
     </GroupStyle>
 </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of `GroupItem` is internal class named `CollectionViewGroupInternal`. You already know that number of items is represented by `ItemCount` on that class. The rest of the puzzle - name of group is represented by `Name` property :) Since that is just enum in your case - you can bind directly to that `Name` property (it contains an instance of your JobState enum).

Comment: thx. I got confused cause in the tutorial there was a `Name` Property on RowLevel too.